# Convert python script output to csv

Tags: python, csv, geolocation, ip-address

I have a small program that is returning results on the location of some users from a database Yay. I want to those results to each be in their own column in a CSV. How would you structure that so that the csv reads IP, Country, City...

```
import pygeoip
import csv

def ipLocator(ip):
    with open('ips.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
         writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
         GeoIPDatabase = 'GeoLiteCity.dat'
         ipData = pygeoip.GeoIP(GeoIPDatabase)
         record = ipData.record_by_name(ip)
         try:
            print("%s" % ip)
            print("%s, %s, %s" % (record['city'], record['region_code'], record['country_name']))
            print("%s" % (record['metro_code']))
         except:
            print("Failed %s" % ip) 

def ip():
    with open('ipaddresses.csv') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        print readCSV
        for row in readCSV:
            print ipLocator(row[0])

        with open('test.csv', 'wb') as fp:
            a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
            data = [['city'],['region_code'],['country_name']]
            a.writerows(data)


ip()
```

Update:

```
import pygeoip
import csv
import os

def ipLocator(ip):
        GeoIPDatabase = 'GeoLiteCity.dat'
        ipData = pygeoip.GeoIP(GeoIPDatabase)
        record = ipData.record_by_name(ip)
        try:
            print("%s" % ip)
            print("%s, %s, %s" % (record['city'],    record['region_code'], record['country_name']))
            print("%s" % (record['metro_code']))
        except:
            print("Failed %s" % ip) 
def ip():
    with open('ipaddresses.csv') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        print readCSV
        for row in readCSV:
            print ipLocator(row[0])

        with open('output.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
            csv_writer.writerows(row[0])

ip()
```

This returns the last ipaddress of the lot printed vertically taking up the first the first column of the csv:

1. 7
2. 4
3. .
4. 2
5. 0
6. 3
7. .

Which is not what I am after

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

especially provide input, desired output.

Comment: What will be the *input* to the function or *piece of code* you wish to achieve or *write*?

Comment: the code takes ipaddresses from ips.csv and uses Geolitecity to return the real world location of the addresses. I want the location to appear in a CSV in the order IP, Country, City,